# SELECT vs SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the difference in doing:

```
SELECT * FROM auth_user;
```

Or doing:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM auth_user;
```

I would think that using `SQL_NO_CACHE` would return the results slower (after the first query), but when I do a `SELECT *` on a table with about 100 rows, the times are identical, even after repeated queries. Why is that?

Comment: Already answered: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777975/when-to-use-sql-no-cache

Comment: @DanB thanks for the link -- I get that. My question is why isn't the query any quicker when using `SQL_NO_CACHE` than when not using it?

Comment: How many times are you running it? It could be building/renewing the cache the first time?

Comment: I tried it, the first time, this take the same time (~0.17s for my case), then with SQL_NO_CACHE, it takes the same time and without  it takes 0.0001s. Check if the cache is disabled... but... it should not.

Comment: Yeah try and check if the cache is disabled. Also, since SQL_NO_CACHE is a query cache no (afaik), you still be using the datacache on mysql (seing as its only a 010 row table, getting it from the memory instead of the disc)

Comment: Sorry -- ... with 100 rows .. the difference would be negligible...try it with a million rows... and I think the cache might show more of a time difference with advanced where clauses and inline sql... run it 1000 times and see... also it matters how you output it.. if you're doing the output everytime... the amount of time to write it would largely be the same (and the writing takes a good percentage of the time if you're doing many iterations).