# How can I make an update statement faster which involves around 300,000 rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ubuntu, optimization

I have a Laravel application which has a common operation where a user fetches around 300,000 rows from a database table called Sign with 3 columns. The table columns are described as follows: `id(int-10), sign(varchar-16), status (int-10)`

The table has around 300 million entries. When a user takes some entries, the status columns of these rows are changed to the id of the user. Note that the user always takes around 300,000 entries at a time.

I have increased the innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_log_file_size to 2GB and 1GB respectively. The system has 3.75GB of RAM.

Here is the code-

```
$collection = Sign::select('sign')
                    ->where('status', 0)
                    ->where(DB::raw('CHAR_LENGTH(sign)'), '=', 7)
                    ->take(300000);

//write the the signs in $collection in a file here

$collection->update(['status' => $user->id]);
```

In my case, the table data is fetched quite easily within less than 1s. The update statement used to take about 100-200s previously but recently I have upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 14 to 16 and after this update statement is taking about 500-600s.
Is there any way to make this process faster? Should I increase the RAM?

Comment: Note that using `take` without `orderBy` does not make much sense, because it is not clear _which_ 300K records you want to take.  To your question about optimizing the update, you might have to add some indices to make that happen.

Comment: This calculation can kill your performance too `->where(DB::raw('CHAR_LENGTH(sign)'), '=', 7)` as it's not really index worthy.  Even if `status` is indexed, indexes only help you with data that is different.  The more different the better it is to index it.  How long does a SELECT (with `SQL_NO_CACHE`) take with this WHERE clause,

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It doesn't really matter which 300K is getting fetched in this case that's why not using orderBy. Any 300K that has char_length=7 and status=0 will work.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix could you please tell me what you mean by SQL_NO_CACHE? The select query doesn't take long, less than a second.

Comment: You just add it in like this `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, foo FROM`  it just tells the DB not to get the results from the cache.  It's better for getting a true idea of the speed of the SELECT.   see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777975/when-to-use-sql-no-cache

Answer (score 0):

Instead of select and update, you have to just hit update query directly like in laravel eloquent,

```
$collection = Sign::where('status', 0)
                ->whereRaw('CHAR_LENGTH(sign) = 7')
                ->update(['status' => $user->id]);
```

In any database select operation will be always fast cause it's just involve scanning of table, you may get more details e.g. `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM sign;`

Comment: But this won't make it any faster will it?

Comment: Try and see. 1 update, means 1 scan rather than twice.

Comment: @AshfaqAdib Please try and experience

Comment: @Chintan7027 Sorry that I forgot to mention, there are some stuffs in between that select and update query so I need that select query separately.

Answer (score 0):

To get over the slowness of `CHAR_LENGTH(sign)` not using an index, [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) provide a solution.

Here we create a sign_length calculated as the length of sign as a column:

```
ALTER TABLE sign ADD sign_length INT UNSIGNED AS (CHAR_LENGTH(sign))
, ADD INDEX status_sign_length(status,sign_length)
```

Then use:

```
$collection = Sign::where('status', 0)
                ->where('sign_length', 7)
                ->update(['status' => $user->id])
                ->take(300000);
```

Note: larvel isn't my strong skill, corrections welcome.

Answer (score 0):

2G for the buffer_pool is dangerously high for a mere 3.75GB of RAM.  Is the system swapping?  If so, either lower the buffer_pool or increase the RAM.  Swapping is terrible for MySQL.

Since the new OS *may* be taking more RAM for itself, the above statement *may* explain the slowdown.

Please provide the SQL generated by `$collection->update(['status' => $user->id]);`; it is *not* obvious what it will be.  For all I know, `$collection` is keeping a list of 300K ids of all the rows and creating a `IN` clause for the `UPDATE`.

`UPDATEing` rows is a lot more costly than `SELECTing` them.  The former must keep a copy of the rows in case there is a crash necessitating a `ROLLBACK`.

What version of MySQL?  There have been recent changes in the Optimizer for `UPDATE`.

If there is stuff between the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE`, you may need `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` -- else another connection could grab the same rows, and make a mess of the data!

Comment: Thank you for your input. The system has been running well with this 2GB of RAM as buffer pool. Also, the lag has been fixed automatically, I guess this was due to the caching. Since the system updated and rebooted, I'm thinking the cache got messed up.

Comment: @AshfaqAdib - 4 bytes for a "status"?  You can probably save 3 bytes/row by using `TINYINT`.

Comment: The status here is an id from another table so I have to have 32-bits.

Comment: @AshfaqAdib - If that is 'normalization', how many different value of `status` are there?  If only a few, then, again, consider `TINYINT` for both tables.

Comment: there are plenty, UINT is the correct data type for it.

Comment: Doesn't Laravel's UINT turns into a 4-byte (or maybe 8-byte?) datatype in MySQL.  This is usually wastes space.